# jQuery closest behaviour in IE very slow

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I have a table with 5000 rows. In each row I have an html element. myElementList is the list of those elements. Now I need to select all the tr's of these elements. I am using the following code.

```
myElementList.closest('tr');
```

This work great in FF. But when I run the same in IE 8. The browser hangs out and a popup messgae appears that propmt for to stop the script.

Any suggestion why I am seeing this behaviour or thier is any alternative.

**Edit**:

The behaviour remains same when I use parents()

```
 myElementList.parents('tr');
```

Comment: Maybe because IE is slow? Try optimizing your code. Be more specific with the selector.

Comment: @Blender can you provide me an optimized one?

Comment: A more optimized version would be to not grab every single TR element at once. Can you provide some context to the question? What's the purpose of selecting everything at once and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need more information on how the table looks (HTML). Your approach uses brute force to find the closest `tr`, but a smarter approach would be to utilize patterns. Will the `tr` *always* be the fourth-level up? Does it have a class/id? Etc.

Comment: @AlecAnanian, actually I have checkbos element in each row. I need to find every tr of selected checkbos. So I have selected checkbos list. But I also need the tr of every selected checkbos.

Comment: @Blender, Actually this is serever control which generates the html. So I cannot assume the level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you wish fairly snappy (the closest parent tr to every checked checkbox) you'd could do something like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    closestByTagName: function(tagname) {
        var tag = tagname.toUpperCase(), i = this.length, node, found=[], trParents;
        while(i--) {
          node = this[i];
          while((node=node.parentNode) && node.nodeName != tag);
            if(node) {
              found[found.length] = node;
            }
        }
        return $(found);
    }

});

var result = $('input:checked').closestByTagName('tr');
```

It isn't pretty, but i can't think of a faster way. (it should beat jQuery by a wide margin)

Comment: Your code throwing error at node && found[found.length]. If I remove node &&, then the firebug console shows undefined instead of tr elements

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fixed version which i have also conveniently wrapped as a jQuery extension. you can see it in use here: http://jsfiddle.net/SWrfm/14/

Comment: Also added a version of the fiddle with 5000 rows, all selected checkboxes - the function is very fast in ie7 :) - be patient for the table to be built tho :P  http://jsfiddle.net/SWrfm/16/

Comment: Thanks. I have just log the result of your plugin. Then found this, console.log(checkBoxList.length)=5000 and console.log(checkBoxList.closestByTagName('tr').length)=0. It seems that plugin is not correct. Sample Html, <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="5000" name="selectedRows" class="singleCheckBox"></td><td>Person5000</td><td>a5000@a.com</td><td>Street, 5000</td></tr>

Comment: The fiddle works as it is supposed to, maybe you have done something wrong when trying to use the code?

Comment: Your own sample result,  console.log($('input:checked').length)=5000 and console.log($('input:checked').closestByTagName('tr').length)=0

Comment: Since my example doesn't have those two log lines in it, it doesn't. would you care to show me your modified example where this happens? You can build on my fiddle and update it with your changes, then maybe i can help you.

Comment: Ahh you are testing in firefox, which doesn't understand `parentElement`. Updated example to use `parentNode` instead, should work in all browsers now., see updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SWrfm/20/

Comment: OK this is fine and much more efficient than jQuery closest. But in Jquery closest elements are stored in top to bottom order and in your case they are stored in bottom to top order. Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: Use a regular `for` loop instead of the `while(i--)` if you wish top to bottom order. it's only marginally slower, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Try using parent(), child(), next(), prev() selectors. I'm not 100% on how exactly jQuery traverses the table to find the tr but 5,000 rows is a lot of traversing. Being more specific would make the js engine do less work.

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

```
$('input:checked').parent('tr').each(function(i){....
```

Comment: I think they all select just one element. I mean if I have 100 elements in the list then they return just one parent. I need all parents.

Comment: parent('tr') starts from a known location and traverses backwards one step until it finds 'tr', which might be 2 steps... closest('tr') probably traverses all 100 elements... which might be 1 to 100 traversals for each checkbox that you described.

Comment: This will not work. parent() will only select the first parent element. While the  parents() will select all elements up to the DOM tree. But parents also behaving the same nehaviour like closest().

Comment: @tank: `.closest` works just like `.parents` except for 2 things: 1: it stops when it finds what it is looking for (thus is usually faster than `.parents`) 2: it starts out doing an `.is` check on the element itself to make sure it isn't already what it's looking for, which makes it slower than `.parents` in rare edge cases.